# Does AWS Mobile SDK support cordova based hybrid application?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, amazon-web-services, react-native

I am planning to develop hybrid application(targetted for iOS and Android)  using  ionic, Angular and cordova, the app will majorly rely on AWS services :amazon s3 for storing and sharing media, SNS for sending push notifications, utilizing lambda for server side logic and cognito for identity

However, I could not find any cordova/phonegap based support in their [SDK page](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/)

Just confirming, is there no support for cordova based hybrid applications?

Is React native is the only option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is plugin by telerik

http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/amazon-aws

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Amazon-AWS --variable ACCESS_KEY=<your Access Key> --variable SECRET_KEY=<your Secret Key>
```